# Возвращение результата ajax запроса через функцию

Tags: jquery, callback

Хочу реализовать вызов ajax запроса через функцию dxs, но ответ всегда получается undefined.

```
dxs: function (url, func) {
 $q = $.getJSON( controller.conf.ajax + "/" + url, {}, function (a) {
  func.apply( this, a );
 })
 .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
  console.log( "Request Failed: " + error );
  switch (jqxhr.status) {
   case 401:
    window.location.replace(controller.conf.home + "?disconnect");
    toastr.error("Вы не автаризованы.");
   break;
   case 403:
     toastr.error("В доступе отказано.");
   break;
   case 404:
     toastr.error("По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.");
   break;
   default:
     toastr.error("Произошла ошибка при выполнение запроса. <b>Error:</b> " + error);
   break;
  }
 });
}
```

Вызов функции

```
Location: function (up) {
 var q = controller.mf.dxs("location/" + up || "", function (data) {
  alert(data);
 });
}
```

Comment: что за dxs ? вы уверены что вам действительно нужно func.apply ? Если уверенны, то уверены ли вы в контексте функции $.getJSON() (по умолчанию это параметры запроса ajax )?    (ну и я практически уверен, что вы возвращаете плохой json)

Comment: json ответ:

    {"title":"test",
    "description":"test",
     "moves":[[1, "test"]]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем ваша главная ошибка -

[у apply - второй аргумент - массив,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> Syntax
>
> fun.apply(thisArg, **[argsArray]**)

т.е. надо делать

```
func.apply(this,[a])
```

чтобы заработало то что у вас там щас, но

this у вас не правильный, т.к. скорее всего вы хотите объект controller а не параметры ajax jquery

http://plnkr.co/edit/ziuSvJKralygQmLjn8lq?p=preview

---

*и это - "Вы не авт**о**ризованы "*

Comment: Спасибо, про то, что нужно передавать параметры массивом забыл :)